# Uncaught exception when running tests: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps$ofRef

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling

I have a project setup using Intellij Idea scala sbt.

> sbtVersion = 1.2.8, scalaVersion = 2.13.0

I am trying to setup gatling but i get the following errors after i run the command :

```
gatling: test
```

> [error] Uncaught exception when running tests:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps$ofRef [error]
>   sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps$ofRef [error]   at
>   io.gatling.sbt.GatlingRunner.tasks(GatlingRunner.scala:31) [error]    at
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run.runTests(ForkMain.java:258) [error]  at
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run.run(ForkMain.java:144) [error]   at
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run.access$100(ForkMain.java:140) [error]    at
>   sbt.ForkMain.main(ForkMain.java:126) [error] Caused by:
>   sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef [error]   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) [error]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) [error]     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) [error]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) [error]    at
>   io.gatling.sbt.GatlingRunner.tasks(GatlingRunner.scala:31) [error]    at
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run.runTests(ForkMain.java:258) [error]  at
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run.run(ForkMain.java:144) [error]   at
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run.access$100(ForkMain.java:140) [error]    at
>   sbt.ForkMain.main(ForkMain.java:126) [info] Simulation(s) execution
>   ended. [error] Error during tests: [error]    Forked test harness
>   failed: java.io.EOFException [error]  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2958)
>   [error]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1538)
>   [error]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>   [error]   at sbt.React.react(ForkTests.scala:177) [error]     at
>   sbt.ForkTests$Acceptor$2$.run(ForkTests.scala:108) [error]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [error] (Gatling / test)
>   sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful [error] Total time: 6 s,
>   completed 29-Aug-2019 09:53:58

**build.sbt**

```
enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)

name := "performance-test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

scalacOptions := Seq(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8", "-target:jvm-1.8", "-deprecation",
  "-feature", "-unchecked", "-language:implicitConversions", "-language:postfixOps")

libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.2.1" % "test,it"
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % "3.2.1" % "test,it"
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "3.0.0")
```

**BasicSimulation.scala**

```
package idcheck

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://google.com")

  val base = scenario("Test")
    .exec(http("base endpoint")
      .get("/"))

  setUp(base.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol))

}
```

Comment: Looks like the issue maybe to do with the scala version 2.13, i downgraded to scalaVersion := "2.12.9" realod and it works

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this error comes with scala 2.13.x, downgrade to 2.12.11 :(

Comment: What is the cause? It's likely not specific to 2.13.x as 2.13 is widely used without issues.