# Is it possible to enforce different scala version for a specific dependency using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-build, scala-version-cross-build

I'm pretty new to scala. While upgrading a multi-module project to Scala 2.13, I found this dependency that is compiled in Scala 2.12 which throws `class not found` exception during runtime

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps$ofRef
```

This class is removed in 2.13. It is available only until [2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps$.html). I am looking for a way to enforce v2.12 to compile **only** this dependency.

I tried to use [cross-building](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html) but that does not work for a core library, because the dependency url constructed using:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value
```

looks like

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library_2.12.15/2.12.15/scala-library_2.12.15-2.12.15.pom
```

Also, cross-building seems to be the way to allow compiling sub-modules with different scala versions with their compatible dependency versions, not meant for enforcing scala versions on individual dependencies.

**Edit 1:**
This is the build definition:

```
   root
    |
    main
    |---dependency w/o 2.13 build
    |
    acceptanceTests
    |---dependency w/o 2.13 build
    |
    (other modules)
```

The dependency is an internal commons library. This uses the class **scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps** during compile time. From **scala-lang -> scala-library**.

**My questions**:

1. Is it even possible to do this? Or is my only option to downgrade to 2.12 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706600/uncaught-exception-when-running-tests-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-scala-col)
2. Why 'core' libraries do not follow the url patters of external libraries like:
   `[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]`.
   `Instead it looks like `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.15/scala-library-2.12.15.pom`

Comment: Does the dependency have a `2.13` release? if not then you can't upgrade or you can't use that dependency.

Comment: No, there isn't a 2.13 release for this dependency. So just to be extra sure I've explained my question correctly . There isn't a way we can do something like:
         1.  enable cross build for the module that uses the dependency.
         2.  when cross-building with  version 2.12, use scala-lang:scala-library:2.12
         3.  package the compiled classes to target/2.12/classes

Comment: A single **Scala** artifact can't contain classes compiled using different **Scala** versions, as simple as that. If there is no `2.13` version of that library then there is no way to use that library on a `2.13` codebase.

Comment: Which library are you talking about? If it's scala-library directly then there are several options. Clarify your build definition and which dependency is problematic.

Comment: @GaëlJ : I have added the build definition. See Edit1

Comment: From what I understand you need to cross compile your _internal commons library_ to Scala 2.12 and 2.13 and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do stuff like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(Keys.scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, 12)) => Seq(
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json"  % "2.6.13"
    )
    case Some((2, 11)) => Seq( 
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.5.18"
    )
    case _ => Seq (
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.11"
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be the solution when there **is** a version of the dependency compiled in 2.13, right? In my case, there isn't such a version. And as mentioned, one of the classes in the dependency uses a class in scala-lang package that's not available in 2.13 there by making it forward incompatible.